# Is there a way to "macro" inputting multiple values into optimize for R?

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
objective.function = function(r.inf, R0){
  right.side = 1 - exp(-R0 * r.inf)
  left.side = r.inf
  return(abs(right.side - left.side))
}

optimize(f = objective.function, interval = c(0,1), R0 = 1.1)
```

My question is, if I have multiple R0 values (e.g., 1, 1.2, 1.7, 4.3...), is there a way I can pass all of those values into the optimize procedure at once and spit them all out, or do I have to just manually change the R0 for each value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

using `sapply`

```
x <- seq(1.1, 1.7, by = .1)
sapply(x, optimize, f = objective.function, interval = c(0,1))
```

or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(x, ~optimize(f = objective.function, interval = c(0,1), R0 = .x))
```

or

```
map_dfr(x, ~optimize(f = objective.function, interval = c(0,1), R0 = .x))
```